# regex for word replace in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

i want to replace al "inc" in the string excluding "inc" in the a word

Hello inc  incWorld inc  inc => hello incworld

```
var str = "Hello inc  incWorldinc inc  inc";

var res = str.toLowerCase()
    .replace(/[^0-9a-z ]/g, " ")
    .replace(/ (corp|inc|llc) ?/g, " ")
    .trim()
    .replace(/\s+/g, " ");
```

but actually i got "hello world"

what is the correct wy to get "hello incworld" insted of "hello world" ?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gataysjL/2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\binc\b
```

You are looking for `\b` that is word boundary.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/tF5fT5/34

```
var re = /\binc\b/gim;
var str = 'Hello inc incWorld inc inc';
var subst = '';

var result = str.replace(re, subst);
```